# this is an function for power implementation i got the logic and code too but in the even case the number and power haven't filled in the output

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, binary-search

this is an function for power implementation I got the logic and code too but in the even case the number and power haven't filled in the output but the output is showing the right answer??

public class Implementpowerfunc {

```
static int powerfunc(int x, int y) {
    if(y==0) {
        return 1;
    }
    int output = 1;
    while(y>0) {
        if(y%2==0) {        // even case(output ??)
            x=x*x;
            y=y/2;
        }
        else {               // odd case 
            output = x*output;
            y--;
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

Comment: Why do you distinguish between even and odd in order to calculate the power function?

Comment: The even case will be followed in a while by an odd case, as at this level `y` is different from 0, and then the `output` will be updated by a value `x` modified in the even case. So the code seems correct effectively, with a complexity O(logn)

Comment: Damien I got you bro thank you, I don't know why I get stuck in these kind of questions

Answer (score 0):

Better to show an example with 2 to the power of 5.

| x | y | output |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 5 | 1 |
| 2 | 4 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 | 2 |
| 16 | 1 | 2 |
| 16 | 0 | 32 |

Comment: Hey I know  that but this is a question on implementation of power function and I can't do it by multiplying x by itself y times because  we have to do it in O of logN time complexity

Comment: Ok I edited my answer to show what the algorithm is doing at each iteration

Comment: No problem. Sorry I misunderstood your question in the first place.